# Invoke endpoint class from Cron Job App Engine - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-endpoints

In my app engine app, i want to update datstore entites from cron service, which will use endpoint method call to update data. But whenever `cron job` is executed, it returns `HTTP 405 status code`. I am not getting where i am going wrong. If anybody has any idea regarding then please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

cron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron/gaevalidatecronjob</url>
        <description>Cron Job that autoreset validity of poster.</description>
        <schedule>every day 00:00</schedule>
        <timezone>Asia/Kolkata</timezone>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ValidityCheckerCron</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.jobaka.dekhbhai.ValidityCheckerCron</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ValidityCheckerCron</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/cron/gaevalidatecronjob</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ValidityCheckerCron extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger _logger = Logger
            .getLogger(ValidityCheckerCron.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        super.doGet(req, resp);

        try {

            _logger.log(Level.INFO, "Cron Job has been executed");

            PosterMasterEndpoint endpoint = new PosterMasterEndpoint();
            CollectionResponse<PosterMaster> response = endpoint
                    .getStarRatedPoster(null, null, null);

            if (response != null && response.getItems() != null
                    && response.getItems().size() > 0) {

                Collection<PosterMaster> collResult = response.getItems();
                ArrayList<PosterMaster> lstResult = new ArrayList<PosterMaster>(
                        collResult);
                Date today = new Date();

                for (PosterMaster posterMaster : lstResult) {

                    Date validityDate = posterMaster.getValidityDate();
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTime(validityDate);
                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, posterMaster.getValidity());
                    validityDate = c.getTime();

                    if (validityDate.getTime() < today.getTime()) {

                        posterMaster.setValidity(0);
                        posterMaster.setStarRated(false);
                        endpoint.updatePosterMaster(posterMaster);

                    }

                    _logger.log(Level.INFO, "Cron Job has been executed for = "
                            + posterMaster.getPosterUrl());
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            _logger.log(Level.INFO, "Problem in ValidityCheckerCron");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doPost(req, resp);
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing super.doGet should fix this issue. The default implementation of servlet methods is to return a method not allowed error (405).

Answer (score 0):

According to the Article [Scheduled Tasks With Cron for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#)

> #### Calling Google Cloud Endpoints
>
> You cannot call a Google Cloud Endpoint from a cron job. Instead, you
>   should issue a request to a target that is served by a handler that's
>   specified in your app's configuration file or in a dispatch file. That
>   handler then calls the appropriate endpoint class and method.